# confused by YAML::NodeType::Undefined with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, parsing, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have a test yaml file that I am trying to parse using yaml-cpp.

test.yaml

```
testConfig:
    # this points to additional config files to be parsed
    includes:
        required: "thing1.yaml"
        optional: "thing2.yaml"
    #some extraneous config information 
    foo: 42
    bar: 394
    baz: 8675309
```

I parse it I get `testConfig.Type()` returns `YAML::NodeType::Map`. And this is expected behavior.

Then, I try to parse the includes to get the required or optional values I can't iterate because `includes.Type()` returns `YAML::NodeType::Undefined`.  I'm really new to yaml and to yaml-cpp so any help showing me where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

parsing code:

```
{includes and other such nonsense} 
            .
            .
            .
YAML::Node configRoot = YAML::LoadFile(path.c_str() );
if( configRoot.IsNull() )
{   
    SYSTEM_LOG_ERROR("Failed to load the config file: %s.",
                    path.c_str());
    return false;
}   

YAML::Node includes = configRoot["includes"];
/*  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 * I believe that here lies the issue as includes is undefined and
 * therefore I cannot iterate over it.
 */
for( auto it = include.begin(); it != include.end(); ++it )
{   
    // do some fantastically brilliant CS voodoo!
}
            .
            .
            .
{ more C++ craziness to follow }
```

**SOLUTION:**
I removed the unnecessary top level `configTest` so that I could parse the includes as I needed.

Comment: There is no need to put quotes around `thingX.yaml` in your YAML file

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the info... I am used to json where it seems that quotes are needed for virtually everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at `configRoot["includes"]`, but the top level key in your map is `testConfig`. Use `configRoot["testConfig"]` instead.

Comment: I just found this and was about to comment!  Thanks for the quick response.  I just removed that superfluous top level testConfig.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your top-level YAML document does indeed not include a key named `includes`. It only contains a key named `testConfig`. You should access that first:

```
// ...
YAML::Node configRoot = YAML::LoadFile(path.c_str())["testConfig"];
// ...
```

Or, if you want to explicitly check if `testConfig` exists:

```
// ...
YAML::Node configRoot = YAML::LoadFile(path.c_str());
// do check her as in your code
YAML:Node testConfig = configRoot["testConfig"];
// check if testConfig is a mapping here
YAML::Node includes = testConfig["includes"];
// ...
```